# Using packer guest_additions_mode "attach"

Tags: virtualbox, packer

**How can the guest_additions_mode "attach" be used in packer to install virtualbox guest additions?**

The [packer documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html) tersely states that

> If the mode is "attach" the guest additions ISO will be attached as a
>   CD device to the virtual machine.

But it does not specify the default mount point.  I'm looking for an example provision script to install the guest additions based on this mount...

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why use `attach` when `upload` is much simpler?

Packer documentation don't say which mount point to use since it's agnostic of the guest OS.

The simplest way to find this out is to run packer with `"headless": false` and a provisioner that does something like `sleep 3600`. And then log in to the VM and check where the DVD is accessible, i.e. reading the output of `dmesg` etc.